# curl: (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user

Tags: curl, ssl

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

when i try this ,I get the this,I thisk my openssl is broken,

```
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0
curl: (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I use -k ,but it always error,
I follow this way https://serverfault.com/questions/437546/centos-openldap-cert-trust-issues
but it error again,how to fix it?

Comment: It is your `pycurl` that is broken.

Answer (score 0):

my here CentOS7 pyspider, run pyspider show error

`Exception HTTP 599 Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user`

and using following steps to fix it:

```
pip3 uninstall pycurl
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib;export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include;pip install pycurl --compile --no-cache-dir
```

detailed description